# Redux Toolkit - An extra reducer method is undefined on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

Using the explicit [documentations](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), I structured a 'home' reducer using the createSlice() method provided by the redux toolkit library and then used an async API call to get offers to store to the redux state using the createAsyncThunk method. Here is the following code for the reducer

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import testService from '../../api/services/test.service';

const getOffers = createAsyncThunk(
  'home/getOffersStatus', //I tried changing the type string but to no avail
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    const res = await testService.getOffers();
    return res.data;
  },
);

const home = createSlice({
  name: 'home',
  initialState: {
    offers: {
      loader: false,
      data: null,
      err: null,
    },
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(getOffers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.offers.data = action.payload
    });

  },
});

export default home.reducer;
```

Next I called the method `getOffers()` inside `home.js`. As shown below:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import {useTheme, withTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {GlobalStyles} from '../../constants/globalStyles';

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOffers());  // <------- Problem Occurs Here
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={GlobalStyles.bgScrollView}
      contentContainerStyle={(GlobalStyles.flex1, GlobalStyles.flexGrow)}>
      <View
        style={{flex: 1, margin: 40, marginTop: '30%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text textAlign="center">{'This is Home Screen'}</Text>
        <Button
          buttonStyle={GlobalStyles.buttonPrimary}
          title="Redeem Offer Screen >"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.push('Redeem Offer');
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default withTheme(Home);
```

Now when I call the dispatch I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: getOffers is not defined at home.js:13`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you're importing the store into some other file in the codebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `getOffers` function is not exported from home reducer file and consequently not imported in `home.js` component.

You should export `getOffers` from your home reducer like:

```
export const getOffers = createAsyncThunk(
```

and then you should import it in your `home.js` component like:

```
import { getOffers } from 'path-to-your-home-reducer-js'; // the relative path to reducer
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I thought the function can simply be exported from within the slice itself. This was not identified in the docs.